# Excel - More efficient way to remove specific borders

Tags: performance, excel, border, vba

How can I make the below code more efficient, at the moment it takes roughly 30 seconds to complete

The code will clear all cells within a selection which have a white background & then clear all diagonal borders within a selection.

With only the clear cells with white background code it finishes instantly but as soon as I added the remove borders code it became slow.

```
Sub ADULTClearOnly()
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ADULT Sign On Sheet")

sh2.Select
Cells.Range("B1:F756").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite Then
    Cell.Value = ""
    End If
    Next
    Cells.Range("G1:AO757").Select
    For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlDiagonalUp Then
    Cell.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You don't need to, and should not `Select` to do these actions
2. Your logic is flawed: `xlDiagonalUp` is not a `LineStyle`
3. Because you are setting any Diagonal Up borders to none, you don't need to iterate the range, do it in one step

So, replace

```
Cells.Range("G1:AO757").Select
For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlDiagonalUp Then
        Cell.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    End If
Next
```

with

```
sh2.Range("G1:AO757").Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
```

---

Similarly,

```
sh2.Select
Cells.Range("B1:F756").Select
For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite Then
        Cell.Value = ""
    End If
Next
```

can be reduced to

```
For Each Cell In sh2.Range("B1:F756")
    If Cell.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbWhite Then
        Cell.ClearContents
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, this now completes instantly.